# How to fix: Android Api 28 DisplayManager#getDisplays() function crashes the app

Tags: android, kotlin, display-manager

I want to use second display in my compact android device with two screen, it already works in Android API 25 but when I try to work it with API 28, I receive an error like this.

My main goal is to check whether display exists, if it exists, show some content on it, if not do nothing. But even the catch block catches the exception, the app crashes.

```
abstract class BaseActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val PRESENTATION_KEY = "presentation"
        const val TAG = "BaseActivity"
    }

    private lateinit var baseApp: BaseApp
    protected var display: Display? = null
    private var presentation: BasePresentation? = null
    private var mContent: PresentationContent? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate")
        baseApp = application as BaseApp

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configureDisplay(savedInstanceState)
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    private fun configureDisplay(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mContent = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(PRESENTATION_KEY)
        }

        try {
            val displayManager = getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as? DisplayManager
            val presentationDisplays = displayManager?.getDisplays(DisplayManager.DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION)
            if (presentationDisplays != null && presentationDisplays.isNotEmpty()) {
                display = presentationDisplays.first()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.message)
        }
    }
}
```

2019-06-24 19:12:00.392 13056-13056/elbepos.puzzle.pos.de E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: elbepos.puzzle.pos.de, PID: 13056
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.Display.getDisplayId()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performConfigurationChangedForActivity(ActivityThread.java:4876)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleActivityConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:5238)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord.lambda$init$0(ActivityThread.java:458)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord$HOrG1qglSjSUHSjKBn2rXtX0gGg.onConfigurationChanged(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performConfigurationChange(ViewRootImpl.java:3899)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2014)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: This stack trace does not seem to be coming directly from the code in your question.

Comment: The workaround is not using the Android Display Service, but to use the Media Router Service. When I change to logic to this, it did not crash any more. You can find the sample of presentation with Media Router Service from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation).